# Error display multiple table select with odbc_connect

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I have a query that I build based on the number of filled search fields.

```
"SELECT * FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                as numero_commande,
                as code_article,
                as mpn,
                as code_cadence,
                as code_fournisseur,
                as nom_fournisseur,
                as date_besoin,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  desc) AS Rank
            FROM
                amflib6. as POI
                JOIN  as V on  = 
                JOIN  as O on  = 
            WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $parametres) . "
        ) X WHERE Rank BETWEEN " . $premier . " AND " . $deuxieme;
```

When I run the query locally with the query below, I get all the fields correctly.

```
$odbcConnect = new PDO("odbc:$dsn", "$userid", "$password");
```

But the production server is on linux and the PDO request does not work anymore. So I use odbc_connect.

```
$odbcConnect = odbc_connect("Driver={IBM i Access ODBC Driver}; system=$mapics_server; uid=$mapics_username; pwd=$mapics_password", "Nothing", "Nothing");
```

Then, I wanted to make a prepared query but I couldn't find anything that worked. So I mixed the prepared query and the classic query.

```
        $rows = array();
        $stmt `= odbc_prepare($odbcConnect, $queryPrepare);
        if (odbc_execute($stmt, $dataParams)) {
            $result = odbc_exec($odbcConnect, $query);
            while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
                dump($row);
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
        } else {
            dump("AHHHHHHHHHHHHH");
            return [];
        }
        odbc_close($odbcConnect);
```

I get the data in array and return.

```
        $arrayObject = array(); 
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $line = new Line();
            $line->setNumeroCommande($row["NUMERO_COMMANDE"]);
            $line->setCodeArticle($row["CODE_ARTICLE"]);
            $line->setMpn($row["MPN"]);
            $line->setCodeCadence($row["CODE_CADENCE"]);
            $line->setCodeFournisseur($row["CODE_FOURNISSEUR"]);
            $line->setNomFournisseur($row["NOM_FOURNISSEUR"]);
            $line->setDateBesoin($row["DATE_BESOIN"]);

            $date_besoin = $line->getDateBesoin();
            $annee = '20' . substr($date_besoin, -6, 2);
            $mois = substr($date_besoin, -4, 2);
            $jour = substr($date_besoin, -2, 2);
            $new_date_besoin = $jour . '/' . $mois . '/' . $annee;
            $line->setDateBesoin($new_date_besoin);
            $arrayObject[] = $line;
        } 
        dump($arrayObject);
        return $arrayObject;
```

the dump displays the right data except for the 2 columns that display weird results.

```
^ array:8 [▼
  "NUMERO_COMMANDE" => ""
  "CODE_ARTICLE" => ""
  "MPN" => ""
  "CODE_CADENCE" => ""
  "CODE_FOURNISSEUR" => b"õððùô÷"
  "NOM_FOURNISSEUR" => b"ı├┴┬@Ã┘ÍõÎ@ãÖüòâà@Ô┴Ô@õÔ─"
  "DATE_BESOIN" => ""
  "RANK" => ""
]
```

I'm trying to display the data from an sql query. Everything works normally locally but when I put the site in production and do a query with odbc_connect instead of PDO, the query doesn't retrieve 2 fields from the query and displays weird data while the other fields are retrieved fine.

Comment: Are those backticks in your PHP code really there? It looks like your output has an encoding problem. Check what character encoding your source has, and how you output them. That information is absent in your question.

Comment: I fixed the backtick in $odbc_connect. how do I check the character encoding of my source?

Comment: I have no experience with "IBM i Access Client Solutions", or whatever you're using, so I can't tell. Far more interesting, for me, is why you simply gave up on using PDO. You can't install drivers?

Comment: When i try to connect with PDO, there are this error "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified in"

Comment: Did you check the [drivers currently supported by your PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php)? See the example on that page, on how to do that. If ODBC is missing it needs to be installed. How you do that depends on your OS.

Comment: For instance, my AlmaLinux 8.6 returns `Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => odbc [2] => pgsql [3] => sqlite )` when I check it.

Comment: it displayed mysql and odbc : ```Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => odbc )```

Comment: Ah, OK. Not what I was expecting.

Comment: So, it is installed. The error message seems incomplete, but it says the name of the data source was not there and the driver name is missing. That could be true. All I have in your question is `$dsn`.

Comment: To me it looks as if you by accident removed mandatory parts of your SQL statement like column and table names in the second and third step of your Edit history

Comment: I managed to use PDO, same problem, the data is badly displayed. They are in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try another type of connection :

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:MyDSN");
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine but I also put "/" instead of "." in the table names in the sql query.